Uploading list and file with [FromForm] in .NET API not working
I have an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API with a request in controller, request model looks like this :
public sealed record CreateInvoiceRequest(
   List<string> Descriptions,
   IFormFile? Attachment,
   List<Tax>? Taxes,
   List<Approver> Approvers
);

I am using it in controller like this :
[HttpPost]
[Route("Create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateInvoice(
    [FromForm] CreateInvoiceRequest request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Code..
}

But when I attach a file in Swagger, data in lists does not reflect in request except List<string>. Means even Taxes and Approvers have three items being sent from Swagger but in controller those appear count as zero.
If I don't include file in the request and try to send the request then all list data is retrieved successfully.
But when I applied debugger and tried to look in HttpContext.Request.Form, I can see that data clearly.
I was earlier using Swashbuckle but I read .NET 9 will no longer ship Swashbuckle.AspNetCore by default because of this issue (FOR REFERENCE), and I was advised to move to NSwag
Now I am using NSwag and facing same issue

Actually, when using [FromForm] with complex request payloads containing lists and file uploads. Despite correctly formatted payloads, the model binding process fails to populate certain list properties like Taxes and Approvers, even though the data is visible in HttpContext.Request.Form. This issue persists even after transitioning from Swashbuckle to NSwag for OpenAPI generation

@MdFaridUddinKiron Do you have any solution to suggest ?

 .ToList()
 .ForEach(x =>
{
 request.Tax= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Tax>>(x.Value);
});``` This  works but it is not efficient way !

Could you please share how are you sending the request, because depending on data bindings you would seen that within your controller Model. I am not sure, if you are getting correct type in your swagger UI.
